# How to select whole rows choosing minimum or maximum values from columns - MySql

Tags: mysql, select

I want to select the rows with unique "created_by" column and picking the row with minimum "distance". Here is my table data:

```
id  title           created_by  last_used           distance
668 Lorem Ipsum 1   981         2012-00-00 00:00:00     12
2   Lorem Ipsum 2   981         2012-00-00 00:00:00     20
710 Lorem Ipsum 3   120         2013-01-01 00:00:00     1
769 Lorem Ipsum 4   981         2012-00-00 00:00:00     4
```

So, I would like to get the following rows:

```
id  title           created_by  last_used           distance
710 Lorem Ipsum 3   120         2013-01-01 00:00:00     1
769 Lorem Ipsum 4   981         2012-00-00 00:00:00     4
```

How can I achieve this with a SELECT statement?

Comment: Well, [what have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: How do you plan to handle two rows having the minimum distance?

Comment: This type of question is very common.  See for example: [1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1799355), [2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11683712), [3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8677307), [4](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12378193), [5](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10700892)

Comment: Using JOINS as stated in the examples I was able to get the results but the performance is not good.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get the results without compromising the performance with this query (avoiding JOINS):

```
SELECT id, title, created_by, last_used, MIN(distance) 
FROM MyTable GROUP BY created_by;
```

Comment: As long as you don't mind the values of `id`, `title`, and `last_used` not necessarily being from the same row as the `MIN(distance)`... that's why the joins are necessary.